# Poor Image Quality Android Camera takePicture()

Tags: android, android-camera

I went through almost all the stackoverflow answers, but my problem is a bit different I believe, The image quality is not that bad as in some of the questions. But as you see the image, you can see the curves. It is not smooth image. [image]

Here is my parameter setting code.

```
Camera.Parameters params=mCamera.getParameters();

List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
Camera.Size size = sizes.get(0);
//Camera.Size size1 = sizes.get(0);
for(int i=0;i<sizes.size();i++)
{

    if(sizes.get(i).width > size.width)
        size = sizes.get(i);


}

//System.out.println(size.width + "mm" + size.height);
params.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);
params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
params.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_AUTO);
params.setWhiteBalance(Camera.Parameters.WHITE_BALANCE_AUTO);
params.setExposureCompensation(0);
params.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
params.setJpegQuality(10);
params.setRotation(90);


mCamera.setParameters(params);
```

I am using `mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try `params.setJpegQuality(100)` instead of `params.setJpegQuality(10)`.

Comment: Hello Sir can you help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39741777/image-quality-is-poor-using-custom-camera#39741777