# Image quality is poor using custom camera

Tags: android, camera

I am using custom camera and working fine but the issue is image is saving with very low (poor) quality. To overcome with it , i have tried all suggestions and implementations. Like  ,

```
parameters.setJpegQuality(100);
parameters.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
```

this is not working. After that i have used

```
List<Size> sizes = cameraParams.getSupportedPictureSizes();
Camera.Size size = sizes.get(0);
for(int i=0;i<sizes.size();i++)
{
 if(sizes.get(i).width > size.width)
 size = sizes.get(i);
}
cameraParams.setPictureSize(mPictureSize.width, mPictureSize.height);
```

This is also not working. Its saving with poor quality still.

**Note :** Camera preview is showing proper with good quality but the issue is when saving captured image to sdcard folder.

Advanced help would be appreciated!!

Comment: after your second code do you resize your `Image`??

Comment: Have you finally added those parameters to your camera after changing them?

Something like mCamera.setParameters(cameraParams);

Comment: how You take a picture from the camera? can you show the code?

Comment: @Prateek Yes I did

Comment: @Ironman No I have not

Comment: @РоманДрогомирецький Its my custom camera preview class

Comment: @Piyush Can you show the Preview image code?

Comment: @GrIsHu Using this http://hastebin.com/curimakitu.java

Comment: @Piyush Have you tried this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19592492/1839336

Comment: @GrIsHu Yes but not looking good still. What changes should i make in my preview class??

Comment: @Piyush Can you access the method `getSupportedPreviewSizes()` method besides `getSupportedPictureSizes()` method ? If you can access it then you would get the exact resolution size of the preview image and can save image as per preview image only. I guess it should help. You don't need to make any changes in preview class.

Comment: In my preview class i m accessing both

Comment: @GrIsHu Issue solved

Comment: @GrIsHu I have posted answer

Comment: @Piyush Thanks !!! :)

Comment: @GrIsHu Wel come :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally my issue solved.

Here I was setting `parameters` for camera preview before i was capturing the image

```
 public void takePicture() {
    mCamera.takePicture(new ShutterCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onShutter() {

        }
    }, new PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        }
    }, new PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(final byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            data1 = data;
            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

So before i called this function in my fragment i have set parameters before this method.

```
mPreview.setParams(params);// This was the mistake what i have done !
mPreview.takePicture();
```

finally solved after removing  `mPreview.setParams(params);`

Comment: i'm looking for this and can you tell me for custom camera what u used? like any library! thank u in advance.

Comment: No. I have not used any custom library. I have used custom class for camera preview and after that i have modified as per my requirement ! Are you working with custom camera ? @RuchaBhatt

Comment: Can you please elaborate your solution. I am setting params to mCamera not mPreview. I am setting params before mCamera.startPreview();
But I am getting low quality image.

Comment: private void setCameraParams() {
Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
        Camera.Size size = sizes.get(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < sizes.size(); i++) {
            if (sizes.get(i).width > size.width)
                size = sizes.get(i);
        }
params.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);
        Camera.Size bestSize = null;
        List<Camera.Size> sizeList = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        bestSize = sizeList.get(0);

Comment: for(int i = 1; i < sizeList.size(); i++){
            if((sizeList.get(i).width * sizeList.get(i).height) >
                    (bestSize.width * bestSize.height)){
                bestSize = sizeList.get(i);
            }
        }
        params.setPreviewSize(bestSize.width,bestSize.height);
        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
        params.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
        params.setJpegQuality(100);
        params.setRotation(90);
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
}

Comment: Couldnt add it in single comment.... 2nd comment is in continuation of first comment.

Comment: I am getting fine quality in some devices and low in others.

Comment: In onSurface changed, calling above method :

 mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                setCameraParams();
                mCamera.startPreview();

Comment: In _surfaceCreated_ method you haven't set params. Why ?

Comment: Check my custom class for [CameraPreview](https://hastebin.com/ipesihudes.java) @seema

Comment: Ok. Will try this way also. Thanks :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135037/discussion-between-piyush-and-seema).

Comment: So in order to set params we need to call mPreview.setParams(params) after mPreview.takePicture() ?

Answer (score 1):

I can show you methods for resetting preview size:

You should change your parameters of preview at Camera.

```
private void setImageSize() {
        Camera.Size size = CameraUtil.findClosetImageSize(mRxCamera.getNativeCamera(), PREFER_SIZE);
        mCamera.getNativeCamera().getParameters().setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);
        WIDTH = size.width;
        HEIGHT = size.height;
    }
```

and after You need to change layout sizes

```
private void resetPreviewSize() {
        final boolean widthIsMax = mWidth > mHeight;
        final Camera.Size size = mCamera.getNativeCamera().getParameters().getPreviewSize();

        final RectF rectDisplay = new RectF();
        final RectF rectPreview = new RectF();

        rectDisplay.set(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight);

        final int width = widthIsMax ? size.width : size.height;
        final int height = widthIsMax ? size.height : size.width;
        rectPreview.set(0, 0, width, height);

        final Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.setRectToRect(rectDisplay, rectPreview, Matrix.ScaleToFit.START);
        matrix.invert(matrix);
        matrix.mapRect(rectPreview);

        mCameraView.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (rectPreview.bottom);
        mCameraView.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (rectPreview.right);
        mCameraView.requestLayout();
    }
```

and if you need

```
public static Camera.Size findClosetImageSize(Camera camera, Point preferSize) {
    int preferX = preferSize.x;
    int preferY = preferSize.y;
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    List<Camera.Size> allSupportSizes = parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();
    Log.d(TAG, "all support Image size: " + dumpPreviewSizeList(allSupportSizes));
    int minDiff = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < allSupportSizes.size(); i++) {
        Camera.Size size = allSupportSizes.get(i);
        int x = size.width;
        int y = size.height;

        int diff = Math.abs(x - preferX) + Math.abs(y - preferY);
        if (diff < minDiff) {
            minDiff = diff;
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return allSupportSizes.get(index);
}
```

Comment: I have my own custom camera preview class